# Insert id from MVC Html.DropDownList into an Html.ActionLink on same page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a Reports Menu in an ASP.NET MVC5 application. On the Reports Menu, I have an Html.DropDownList showing a list of programs. I want the user to select a program, and then click "Run" and post to something like: Reports/ClassList/14. In other words I want new {id=???} to contain the selected dropdownlist id.

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>Choose a Program:</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownList("ProgramId", String.Empty)</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Class List</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Run", "ClassList", "Reports", new { id = ???})</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How do I "insert" the selected ProgramId from the dropdown into the link parameters when the page posts?

Do I need to use JavaScript for it?

Thanks,

Sanjeev

Answer (score 1):

Add a class on ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Run", "ClassList", "Reports", new { id=""},new {class = "ClassList"})
```

Html generated for it will be this:

```
<a href="/Reports/ClassList/" class="ClassList">Run</a>
```

and write dropdown change event and set id it:

```
$('select[name="ProgramId"]').change(function(){


$(".ClassList").attr("href",$(".ClassList").attr("href")+$(this).val());

});
```

and after appending with jquery it will become:

```
<a href="/Reports/ClassList/Id" class="ClassList">Run</a>
```

Comment: Hi Ehsan, I think you meant to add an "@" sign in new {@class = "ClassList"}? My code still doesn't work. I inserted the JS in my layout file and still not rendering. Here's my code:

Comment: Sorry my new code cannot be added here for some reason. But I basically added the script to the head tag of my Layout file. And the new {@class = "ProgramId"} to the ActionLink. But nothing happens when I click run, it still posts without any ids appended. Is my JS code in the wrong place? Do I need to do anything with the render tags?